# give month name as column aliase dyanamically in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need month name in column aliase.for example:

```
select d.Job_name,  nvl(a.cnt,0) as May, nvl(b.cnt,0) as June, nvl(c.cnt,0) as July
from (query);
```

here I am hardcoding May,June and july as column aliase name.I need them dynamically.

i need below:

```
select d.Job_name,  nvl(a.cnt,0) as (current_monthe-2), nvl(b.cnt,0) as (current_month-1), nvl(c.cnt,0) as current_month
from (inner query)
```

Please assist me on this.Let me know if any other information required.Thanks!

Comment: SQL queries return result sets with fixed column names.  The only way to do this is using dynamic sql, via an `execute immediate` statement (or some similar construct).

Comment: It sounds like you may have wanted to PIVOT in your inner query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build dynamic query to put columns names as you wish, example:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select d.Job_name,  nvl(a.cnt,0) as '|| to_char(add_months(SYSDATE, -2), 'Month') ||', nvl(b.cnt,0) as '|| to_char(add_months(SYSDATE, -1), 'Month') || ', nvl(c.cnt,0) as ' || to_char(SYSDATE, 'Month') || ' from (inner query)'
into v_values_set;
```

Do what you wish with static sql is quite difficult, maybe it is possible to play with PIVOT option to set up columns names dynamically.

Comment: i don't what to run under begin and end; block(execute immediate runs in pl/sql blocks).any way to do this by normal sql:i tried this nad want to run in this way:select a.count  as '|| to_char(add_months(SYSDATE, -2), 'Month') ||' from (innery query) but it through error. Any other solution for this.Plz suggest